# What is best approach to designing a local-to-cloud cloud-to-local Infrastructure?

Tags: design-patterns, mysql, synchronization, database-development, data-replication

I plan to have a cloud web application(CWA) and several local web application(LWA), let's assume 3 LWAs and 1 CWA. CWA === LWA.

This web application would consist of a database server, file storage server, An Application server.

I have two options for synchronisation:

**Option 1:**

A record saved in LWA-1 would reflect in the CWA and LWA-2 and LWA-3 and vice versa (it might not be real-time and I'll explain why in a bit).

**Option 2:**
A record saved in LWA-1 would not reflect in LWA-2 and LWA-3 BUT would sync to the CWA. Same goes for other LWAs. Essentially, The CWA aggregates data synced from all LWAs.

*Main Challenges:*

1. Internet connection is really really unreliable and bad so synchronisation will happen at intervals when Internet will be stable. This is why I'm relying heavily on local systems and not a complete cloud solution.
2. Avoiding Duplicate keys on synchronisation.
3. Ensuring Data Integrity.
4. Maintaining unique records. E.g client A registered on LWA-1 must not be able to re-register on LWA-2 and LWA-3.

**I need your bright minds to help determine the best approach to designing this whole system.**

Techs: NodeJS, MySql, Linux, python

Comment: Which option is better depends almost entirely on the services your application is offering and what data needs to be synchronized and to whom from a business perspective and what data could be processed entirely locally.

Comment: To avoid key duplication, I would suggest each local application requests a range of id's from the cloud application (say, a thousand ids). This way it can keep issuing new Ids for new data records knowing there will never be a key-conflict from other local applications. Having reserved a range of id's instead of asking every time you need a new one also allows you to keep operating when the internet connection is down.